# static date as start point into timer

Tags: php, javascript

I have a actual date from php script. When I'll include it into the js script it will be not he same as dynamic js 'new Date()'. I must use the date from php (at this point I can't use the same from js) to js script but this date must stay dynamic.

How to change static date from $time_local_js into dynamic date similar to js new Date() to use into this countdown script? An pararell clock?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
d_new=+new Date(2012,11,6,21,00,00);  
d_old= new Date(<?php echo $time_local_js ?>);  
(function(){ 
sec=(d_new-d_old)/1000; 

document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=~~(sec/(3600*24))+' days '+~~(sec/3600)%24+' hours '+~~(sec/60)%60+' min '+~~sec%60+' sek'; 

setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000)})() 
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it must stay dynamic"? I can't quite understand the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

From you last comments, now I believe you don't need PHP at all for this. Maybe to set `d_new`, depending on the case. But `d_old` has to be redefined every time the function is called by the timer. Is this what you need?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var d_new=+new Date(2012,11,6,21,00,00);  
(function(){ 
    var d_old= new Date();
    sec=(d_new-d_old)/1000; 
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=~~(sec/(3600*24))+' days '+~~(sec/3600)%24+' hours '+~~(sec/60)%60+' min '+~~sec%60+' sek'; 
    setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000)
})();
</script>
```

Comment: hmm, script is not working, something with the syntax error. THe php date value is from : $time_local_js = date('Y,m,d,H,i', strtotime('now'));

Comment: Who says "syntax error"? PHP or JS? Since your PHP var is already correctly formatted, your original example should work.

Comment: I did change it into  var date = new Date(<?php echo date('Y,m,d,H,i,s', strtotime('now')); ?>); Timer is displaying but is stoping.

Comment: probably problem is with new Date(). When I include inside this my date like f.ex -> var date = new Date(2012,03,01,10,10,10); the timer is stopping too.

Comment: Please check my last edit (actually, a complete rewrite of my answer).

Comment: thnks, in this form it's working. But with included date from php it's stopping.

Comment: the page refreshing is not a problem anyway - always we have the countdowning time - going to the 00:00:00

Comment: I don't understand what you need the PHP date for. You were using it as the current date, and that can be done from js instead. Every time the timer runs, you have to get a new current date, or the timer won't move.

Comment: The date from PHP is a part of bigger script, with Time_zone offset. Than I must use the same value of Time in few places of my script. Then this value of time MUST BE from the same, one source. On the one page I have f.ex. 10 places where I want to show the time counter with a ending dates coming from dbase and actual dates from the Time_zone offset code. And, of course, the Time_zone value is used to changing the displaying time for every events on my page.

Comment: Why the script is working with a time value coming from a finger wrote but not with a time value coming from the inside php code? that's a question ....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8678/discussion-between-bfavaretto-and-andrew)